# Vertical sum and coordinates relative to separators

Tags: org-mode, org-table

In `org-mode`, I can sum the rows in a column as follows:

```
|   | Column 1 |
|   |          |
|---+----------|
|   |        1 |
| 2 |        2 |
| 3 |        3 |
|   |        4 |
|---+----------|
|   |          |
|---+----------|
#+TBLFM: @7$2=vsum(@I..@II)
```

However, if I add some lines in the middle, the coordinates of `@7$1` will move. According to the [documentation](http://orgmode.org/manual/References.html#References), I've tried to modify the formula to

```
#+TBLFM: @II+1$2=vsum(@I..@II)
```

However, the result for the last line is:

```
|---+----------|
| 5 |       10 |
|---+----------|
```

Why is it also summing the first column ?

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you wanted this: `#+TBLFM: @>$2=vsum(@<<$2..@>>$2)`, right?

Comment: If you add rows with `M-S-down`, the formulas are updated automatically. E..g. adding one row will update the formula in the first example to `@8$2=...`

Comment: With respect to your question, the fact that `@II+1$2` also updates the first column is unexpected, and deserves a bug submission.

Comment: FWIW, you cannot use hline relative reference on the left hand side, at least from what I see on the latest org built from its master (dev) branch. I get this error: `user-error: Can’t assign to hline relative reference`.

Answer (score 1):

```
#+TBLFM: @II+1$2=vsum(@I..@II)
```

Doesn't do anything for me *(org-version 8.3.1)*, but this works:

```
#+TBLFM: @>$2=vsum(@I..@II)
```

ie: *last row* of table.

Comment: But how to put the sum in the row after the second separator, and not necessarily in the last row of the table ?

Comment: @Klaus I do not think that you can use the hline references (like `I` and `II`) on the left hand side in the equations. I get this error `user-error: Can’t assign to hline relative reference` when I try to do so on the latest org built from its master (dev) branch.